# Adding Google star Rating to the search Result

Tags: seo, meta-tags

I need to add *star rating* to my site for showing the star image rating in search results. I did a search on the internet and read a few articles on it. It is basically Microformats and the related tags. I'm still confused about the review. What if I need to use the tripadvisor review and rating on the search results. How can I do that or can anybody tell me about the code that I need to put in to my pages. I'm sorry for not being sound to this question.

Comment: The ratings come from content on _your_ site, not someone else's (ie. tripadvisor) if that is what you are implying?

Comment: So what exactly i need to do as my first step for putting those star in the search Result. I m totally confused.

Comment: Create/Install a review system. Then you'll need to get big enough that Google will consider showing the *s in their search results.

Comment: But most of the Website with those start doesn't have any Rating system installed in there Site, this is what is confusing me !

Answer (score 2):

Use schema.org

If you are using WordPress for your CMS, then Raven tools has a great plug-in which does this, also GD Star Rating plug-in.

Comment: I want to use it in my website and joomla is my CMS

Comment: @GouravJude Prasad answered your question. You have to use Microformats on your website, which specify the rating, how many votes have been made, etc. everything you need to know including specific examples are on schema.org direct link: http://schema.org/Rating

Comment: @uberconversion I disagree that **everything you need to know is located at [schema.org](https://schema.org)**. The documentation for adding microformats to your website is extremely vague in my opinion. That being said, an excellent way to learn the proper format is to view the source code of authority websites.

Comment: @AndrewSmallwood I am pretty late to the party, but I'd be very interessted to know, what documentation on schema.org is extremely vague? Hands down, I have seen better documentation around, but if you are looking at documentation expecting to get a copy/paste manual, sorry, that is not what documentation is actually about. Every possible use-case is available on schema.org, in Microdata, RDFa, even JSON-LD. My argument still holds in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Use the schema.org markup. You'll need to have a way to collect reviews with star-ratings from your users, and then display them on the appropriate pages with the correct markup. Also, the reviews should be unique to each page.

Once you've done this, run a few of them through the [Google Rich Snippets tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets). If they appear okay there, then just sit back and wait. It can often take a long time before the star ratings show up in SERPs, if they show up at all (I believe this is largely affected by the authority of your domain).